# Outputting HTML unordered list python

Tags: python, html, string

I'm attempting to write a function with python that will take an list of strings that I have defined and display them as a single string that is and HTML unordered list of said strings. So far my code is:

```
def pizzatoppings(self):
    toppings = ['mushrooms', 'peppers', 'pepparoni', 'steak', 'walnuts', 'goat cheese', 'eggplant', 'garlic sauce'];
    for s in toppings:
        ul += "<li>"+str(s)+"</li>"
        ul += "</ul>"
        return ul
```

When I attempt to run this however I get no traceback and nothing happens. Does anyone know why this is happening? I know this is probably a trivial question but I've searched for answers and cannot find a solution. Thanks!

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: I am saving the file as pizzatoppings.py and running it in my terminal window with `$ python pizzatoppings.py`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do something like that:

```
def print_ul(elements):
    print("<ul>")
    for s in elements:
        ul = "<li>" + str(s) + "</li>"
        print(ul)
    print("</ul>")

toppings = ['mushrooms', 'peppers', 'pepparoni', 'steak', 'walnuts', 'goat cheese', 'eggplant', 'garlic sauce'];
print_ul(toppings)
```

There were some problems with your original code:

- you did not *call* the function, so no wonder it didn't do anything
- even if you did, the function did not actually *print* anything, it just returned some values
- the function didn't really take arguments, so it was not re-usable at all

A better (IMO) solution would be to have a function generating the HTML code, and printing the result:

```
def ulify(elements):
    string = "<ul>\n"
    for s in elements:
        string += "<li>" + str(s) + "</li>\n"
    string += "</ul>"
    return string

print(ulify(['thing', 'other_thing']))
```

You can also read about [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It would make working with lists simpler:

```
def ulify(elements):
    string = "<ul>\n"
    string += "\n".join(["<li>" + str(s) + "</li>" for s in elements])
    string += "\n</ul>"
    return string
```

Comment: I can't believe I was forgetting to call the function, thanks for your help I've marked your answer as correct.

Comment: @NoOrangeJuice I'm glad! I can help you improve it a bit if you want ;)

Comment: Using a function to generate the code looks much simpler actually, thanks again!

Comment: It's simpler indeed, and much more composable. You can use the generated text in other functions, or even print to a file instead of you terminal. Functions are good, use them! (and especially those which are already built-in!)

Answer (score 3):

I was just doing this at work today. Here's my two-line solution:

```
def example(elements):
    return '<ul>\n' + '\n'.join(['<li>'.rjust(8) + name + '</li>' for name in elements]) + '\n</ul>'
```

Which gives:

```
<ul>
    <li>mushrooms</li>
    <li>peppers</li>
    <li>pepparoni</li>
    <li>steak</li>
    <li>walnuts</li>
    <li>goat cheese</li>
    <li>eggplant</li>
    <li>garlic sauce</li>
</ul
```

This makes the generated HTML code a little easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to build a website. Why don't you use a template engine, like Jinja 2 for this, instead of printing a HTML snippet from a function? For that you will need a Python web application, plausibly written in one of web frameworks. I'd go for [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) here, it's simple to start working with and Jinja is a default template engine for Flask.

If you just want to generate static HTML files, I would recommend [Frozen-Flask](http://pythonhosted.org/Frozen-Flask/), which allows you to generate static HTML files that can be hosted without a need to deploy any Python web application on your server. Just copy generated files to your hosting and you are ready to go.

If you still want to just print a HTML snippet, your code should be something like Ealhad posted in his answer.

Also, you original code contains a few problems:

```
def pizzatoppings(self):
    # you don't need semicolons in Python
    toppings = ['mushrooms', 'peppers', 'pepparoni', 'steak', 'walnuts', 'goat cheese', 'eggplant', 'garlic sauce']
    # you need to initialize a "ul" variable
    ul = "<ul>"
    for s in toppings:
        ul += "<li>"+str(s)+"</li>"
    # following two lines where indented too much. In Python, indentation defines a block of code
    ul += "</ul>"
    return ul
```

Comment: I'm actually more familiar with template engines, and I agree they are much simple to use. However I'm trying to write the html snippet as a proof of concept kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this instead and it was a little simpler for me

```
for item in items:
    html_str += "<li>" + str(item) + "</li>\n"
html_str += "</ul>"


print(html_str)
```