# How to insert python lists in HTML table?

Tags: python, html

I have the following output list from python list.

`['N3132-a', '172.20.138.18', '192.168.193.15/24', 'N3132-a.td.com ', 'N3K-C3132Q-40GX', 'FOC2116XCFV', 'NXOS: version 7.0(3)I4(6)']`

`['N56k-a', '10.249.98.11', '192.168.173.16/24', 'N56k-a.td.com ', 'N5K-C56128P', 'FOC2187FGHJ', 'kickstart: version 7.1(4)N1(1)']`

`['N3164-b', '172.16.48.14', '192.168.130.12/24', 'N3164-b.td.com ', 'N3K-C3164Q-40GE', 'FDO26HJKL2', 'NXOS: version 7.0(3)I4(6)']`

`['5596-a', '10.250.98.20', '192.168.170.25/24', '5596-a.td.com ', 'N5K-C5596UP', 'FOX2398HGF', 'kickstart: version 7.1(4)N1(1)']`

`['N3064-B', '172.17.47.20', '192.168.130.25/24', 'N3064-B.td.com ', 'N3K-C3064PQ-10GX', 'FOC193FGHJNM', 'NXOS: version 7.0(3)I4(6)']`

I need to loop this data in html and print this in html table .

I have the following html code which works but creating each table instead of one table

Manual input work like this

```
<HTML>
<head>
<title>Data</title>

</head>
<body>

    <h1><marquee>Welcome To The Page</marquee></h1>
    <h1>Data :</h1>

    <table  border="4" align="center">


     <th style="background-color:yellow !important;"><h2><br>dc</h2></th>
     <th style="background-color:yellow !important;"><h2><br>proxi</h2></th>
     <th style="background-color:yellow!important;"><h2><br>id</h2></th>
     <th style="background-color:yellow !important;"><h2><br>email</h2></th>
     <th style="background-color:yellow!important;"><h2><br>face-1</h2></th>
     <th style="background-color:yellow!important;"><h2><br>face-2</h2></th>
     <th style="background-color:yellow!important;"><h2><br>face-3</h2></th>
     <tr><td>N3132-a</td><td>172.16.139.15</td><td>192.168.195.15/24</td><td>N3132-a.td.com </td><td>N3K-C3132Q-40GX</td><td>FOC2116</td><td>NXOS: version 7.0(3)I4(6)</td></tr><tr><td>N56k-a</td><td>10.249.99.11</td><td>192.168.175.11/24</td><td>N56k-a.td.com </td><td>N5K-C56128P</td><td>FOC2109L</td><td>kickstart: version 7.1(4)N1(1)</td></tr>

</table>
</body>
</HTML>
```

need to loop that input data in python and print that html file instead of manual data in html table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outputting HTML unordered list python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050683/outputting-html-unordered-list-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to turn a list into an HTML table in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475123/easiest-way-to-turn-a-list-into-an-html-table-in-python)

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far

Comment: i had added the code

Answer (score 0):

You can put whole html in python variable and for list output , you can do like this:

```
l=['N3132-a', '172.20.138.18', '192.168.193.15/24', 'N3132-a.td.com ', 'N3K- 
C3132Q-40GX', 'FOC2116XCFV', 'NXOS: version 7.0(3)I4(6)']
for item in l:
   print('<td>'+item+'</td>')
```

Comment: how do i add that to html

Comment: You can edit you code file writing in file like [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064938/python-html-for-loop-format]

Comment: <td>d</td><td>N</td><td>3</td><td>1</td><td>-</td><td>3</td><td>2</td><td>-</td><td>a</td>       instead of <td>N3132-a</td>